# php form & multiple results on same page with auto refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating a call screen for a radio station. I want the form in a div on the left & the results in a div on the right. There are 6 phone lines so all 6 lines should be able to be displayed at once. I want to state how long each caller is holding on the line on top of their info. I have created 2 php files. One labeled cm.php which has the form & the other cm2.php which puts the form results in the div on the right side of the page. I am new to php & ajax so I can't figure out how to get the results in the div on the right with a delete button so when the caller hangs up, their info goes away. I have searched here & all over the web for weeks & can't get the submitted form results to show on the right side of the page when using 2 php files. The ajaxSetup does put cm2.php on a div on the right, but doesn't include the form results so cm2.php needs the correct code. It also is refreshing the the whole html when it's suppose to only refresh the right div: #submitted info when the form is submitted. What code do I need? My code is below:

**cm.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<Meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-
1252">
<title>Call Mananger</title>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-
validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup(
cache: false
});
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#submittedInfo').load('cm2.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
<style> <?php include 'call manager.css'; ?> </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="callerInfo">
<form name="info" action="cm.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"
method="post">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Line</td>
<td>
<select name="select" id="line">
<option value="Line 1: ">1</option>
<option value="Line 2: ">2</option>
<option value="Line 3: ">3</option>
<option value="Line 4: ">4</option>
<option value="Line 5: ">5</option>
<option value="Line 6: ">6</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td> 
<input type="text" name="name" value>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Town</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="town" value>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Topic</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="topic" value>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type='submit' value='Submit Caller' name="submit">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form> 
</div>
<div id="submittedInfo">
No Callers
</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

**cm2.php**

```
<?php

echo "Waiting: ". date('i:s'). '</b><br>';
echo 'Line: '.$.post['select'];
echo '- '. $.post['name']. '</b><br>';
echo 'Town: '. $_POST['town']. '</b><br>';
echo 'Topic: '. $_POST['topic'].'</b><br>';
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="cm.php">
<input type="hidden" name="listenerInfo" value="">
<input type="submit" name="deleteCaller" value="Delete Caller"> 
</form>
```

Comment: There is some invalid markup in `cm.php`  - for instance `<div id="submittedInfo"` is missing the closing `>` but perhaps more importantly your ajax function is attempting to load an entire html page into the same page which would mean the page `cm.php` would have two head sections, two body sections etc etc. You could use an `iframe` within `cm.php` that loads `cm2.php` which might be a better solution perhaps?I would suggest that for really low latency for this type of app websockets would be ideal.

Comment: To me it seems like there are several pieces of the puzzle missing - it is simple enough to complete the form and have it populate in another part of the same page but I simply cannot see what, if anything, `cm2.php` does or is supposed to do. How does this system tie in with the telephony system? Where is `cm2.php` getting it's data from every second ( `setInterval` is loading what?? ) - a database, telephony system.

Comment: @RamRaider When a listener calls in, they give us their info & it's posted on the same screen as the form so that the host knows who is on waiting on the line to talk to them. There could be 6 people holding at once so all their info has to be on the screen at the same time as the form along with a delete button underneath them so that when they hang up, all of that caller's info goes away from the screen. cm2.php is suppose to display callers info after hitting the submit caller button. If I can accomplish this with 1 php file, then great. Please tell me how to do it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: _“The ajaxSetup does put cm2.php on a div on the right, but doesn't include the form results so cm2.php”_ - of course it doesn’t, because you are not send any data to that script ... $.load has a second parameter for that, but be aware it sends a GET request. If you want to send the data via POST, then you have to use $.post and handle inserting the result into the target element yourself in the success handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bit of spare time so put together a demo of how you could do this all on one page using sessions. There is no jQuery ( I don't use it ) so you might need to adjust the ajax calls appropriately - no doubt there are various methods on offer within jQuery which could streamline the following code.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $maxlines=6;    #how many phone lines - default 6
    $svar='calls';  #session variable name

    /* create a new session variable if it does not already exist */
    if( !isset( $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) )$_SESSION[ $svar ]=array();

    /* Process ajax POST requests */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST ) ){
        ob_clean();

        $cmd=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'cmd', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $line=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'line', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );


        if( $cmd ){
            switch( $cmd ){
                case 'poll':
                    $json=json_encode( $_SESSION[ $svar ] );
                break;
                case 'add-caller':
                    $_POST['time']=date('H:i:s');
                    $_SESSION[ $svar ][ $line ]=$_POST ;
                    $json=json_encode( $_SESSION[ $svar ] );
                break;
                case 'delete':
                    if( $line && array_key_exists( $line,$_SESSION[ $svar ] ) ) unset( $_SESSION[ $svar ][ $line ] );
                    $json=json_encode( $_SESSION[ $svar ] );
                break;
            }
        }
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        exit( $json );
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Call Manager</title>
        <style>
            html, html *{font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;font-size:1rem;box-sizing:border-box;}
            #container{width:95%;float:none;margin:0 auto;box-sizing:border-box;}
            #lhs{width:calc(20% - 2rem );float:left;height:80vh;}
            #rhs{width:calc(80% - 2rem );float:right;height:80vh;}
            #lhs,#rhs{display:block;clear:none;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0 1rem}
            input[type='button']{float:none;display:inline-block;margin:1rem auto;}
            input[type='text'],select{width:100%;padding:0.5rem;}
            table{width:100%;}
            td{text-align:center;}
            tr td:not([colspan]):first-of-type{text-align:left;}
            h1{font-size:2rem;text-align:center;}
            h2{font-size:1.25rem;text-align:center;}
            pre{clear:both;}
            ul,li{ display:block; width:100%;float:left;}
            li:nth-of-type(even){background:whitesmoke;}
            option[disabled]{background:rgba(255,0,0,0.25)}
            li{padding:0.25rem 1rem;}
            li div span{font-weight:bold;margin:0 0 0 2rem;}
            li div input{ color:red;float:right!important;clear:none; }
        </style>
        <script>

            var _int;
            var _poll=2.5;

            function ajax(m,u,p,c,o){
                /*
                    Utility function for basic Ajax requests
                    m = method ~ GET or POST only
                    u = url ~ the script or resource to which the request will be sent
                    p = parameters ~ an object literal of parameters to send
                    c = callback ~ asynchronous callback function that processes the response
                    o = options ~ object literal o foptions which are also passed to callback

                */
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call( this, xhr.response, o, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() );
                };
                if( o.hasOwnProperty('formdata') && o.formdata===true && m.toLowerCase()=='post' ){
                    /* send formdata object "as-is" ~ set p = FormData */
                } else {
                    var params=[];
                    for( var n in p )params.push( n+'='+p[ n ] );
                    switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
                        case 'post': p=params.join('&'); break;
                        case 'get': u+='?'+params.join('&'); p=null; break;
                    }
                }
                xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
                if( !o.hasOwnProperty('formdata') ) xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                if( o && Object.keys( o ).length > 0 && o.hasOwnProperty('headers') ){
                    for( var h in o.headers )xhr.setRequestHeader( h, o.headers[ h ] );
                }
                xhr.send( p );
            }

            function createNode( t, a, p ) {
                try{
                    /*
                        utility function to simplify creation of new DOM nodes
                        t = type ~ node type or tag name of node
                        a = attributes ~ object literal of attributes to add to node
                        p = parent ~ the DOM node to which the new node will be added
                    */
                    var el = ( typeof( t )=='undefined' || t==null ) ? document.createElement( 'div' ) : document.createElement( t );
                    for( var x in a ) if( a.hasOwnProperty( x ) && x!=='innerHTML' ) el.setAttribute( x, a[ x ] );
                    if( a.hasOwnProperty('innerHTML') ) el.innerHTML=a.innerHTML;
                    if( p!=null ) typeof( p )=='object' ? p.appendChild( el ) : document.getElementById( p ).appendChild( el );
                    return el;
                }catch(err){
                    console.warn('createNode: %s, %o, %o',t,a,p);
                }
            }





            function bindEvents( event ){
                /* get references to dom nodes */
                var form=document.getElementById('caller-info');
                var select=form.querySelector('select');
                var rhs=document.getElementById('rhs').querySelector('ul');

                /* utility functions */
                var _clearform=function(){
                    Array.prototype.slice.call( form.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]') ).forEach(function(n){n.value=''});
                };
                var _disable=function(i){
                    select.querySelector('option[data-id="'+i+'"]').disabled=true;
                };
                var _enable=function(i){
                    select.querySelector('option[data-id="'+i+'"]').removeAttribute('disabled');
                };
                var _deletecaller=function(e){
                    _enable.call( this, this.dataset.id );
                    _setcaller.call( this, this.dataset.id, 'Line '+this.dataset.id )
                    this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild( this.parentNode.parentNode );
                };
                var _setcaller=function(i,name){
                    select.querySelector('option[data-id="'+i+'"]').innerHTML=name;
                }


                /* ajax config */
                var method='post';
                var url=location.href;
                var options={ formdata:true, node:rhs, clear:true };
                var callback=function(r,o,h){
                    /* clear text fields in the form */
                    if( o.clear===true ) _clearform.call( this );

                    var data=JSON.parse( r );
                    for( var n in data ){

                        var json=data[n];
                        var id='caller_'+json.line;
                        /*
                            change attributes of select menu
                            and change the displayed text of 
                            selected option to indicate the line
                            is busy
                        */
                        _enable.call( this, json.line );
                        _disable.call( this, json.line );
                        _setcaller.call( this, json.line, 'Line '+json.line+' - '+json.name );


                        /*
                            if there is NOT a node with id ( as above )
                            then create a new `li` node with child content
                            including the `delete` button to which a new
                            `onclick` event listener is added.
                        */
                        if( !document.getElementById( id ) ){
                            var li=createNode( 'li', { id:id }, o.node );
                            var div=createNode( null,{ 'data-id':json.line, innerHTML:'<span>Line:</span> '+json.line+' <span>Name:</span> '+json.name+' <span>Town:</span> '+json.town+' <span>Topic:</span> '+json.topic+' <span>Waiting since: </span>' + json.time },li);
                            var bttn=createNode( 'input', { type:'button',value:'Delete','data-id':json.line }, div );
                                bttn.onclick=function( event ){
                                    ajax.call( this, method, url, { cmd:'delete', line:this.dataset.id }, _deletecaller.bind( this ), { node:rhs } );
                                }.bind( bttn );
                        }
                    }
                    /*
                        If there are no child nodes (`li`) to the
                        `ul` - stop polling
                    */
                    if( o.node.childNodes.length==0 ){
                        clearInterval( _int );
                        _int=Number.NaN;
                        console.info('stop polling...');
                    }
                };


                var _beginpolling=function(){
                    if( isNaN( _int ) ){
                        console.info('start polling...');
                        _int=setInterval(function(){
                            ajax.call( this, method, url, { cmd:'poll' }, callback, { node:rhs, clear:false } );
                        }, 1000 * _poll );
                    }
                };



                /* Add caller - event listener assigned to `Submit Caller` button */
                var evtSubmitCaller=function( event ){
                    /*
                        rather than manually collecting form field parameters
                        and processing into a payload to send in the request, 
                        use the `FormData` object ~ adding ( append ) a custom
                        parameter `cmd`
                    */
                    var fd=new FormData( form );
                        fd.append('cmd','add-caller');
                    ajax.call( this, method, url, fd, callback, options );
                    _beginpolling.call( this );
                };
                form.querySelector('input[type="button"]').onclick=evtSubmitCaller;




                /* Poll every n seconds */
                _beginpolling.call( this );

            }
            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents, false );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Call Manager</h1>
        <div id='container'>
            <div id='lhs' data-id='callerInfo'>
                <form id='caller-info' method='post'>
                    <h2>Add Caller</h2>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Line</td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name='line'>
                                    <?php
                                        for( $i=1; $i <= $maxlines; $i++ ){
                                            $caller = !empty( $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) && array_key_exists( $i, $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) ? 'Line '.$i.' - '.$_SESSION[ $svar ][ $i ]['name'] : "Line $i";
                                            $disabled = !empty( $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) && array_key_exists( $i, $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) ? 'disabled=true' : '';
                                            echo "<option data-id='$i' value='$i' $disabled>$caller";
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td> 
                                    <input type='text' name='name' />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Town</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type='text' name='town' />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Topic</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type='text' name='topic' />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan=2>
                                    <input type='button' value='Submit Caller' />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id='rhs' data-id='submittedInfo'>
                <ul></ul><!-- will be populated by ajax callback -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Please excuse my ignorance, but I just started programming 6 months ago learning html, css, & Javascript. Your code is way over my head! I put it your code in cm.php & get a blank screen. Under inspect, it shows nothing in the head or body. I put it in an html file & get the form, but no results & lots of errors. Thank you for your time! Wish it worked!

Comment: copy and paste the entire code - save as, for instance, `call_manager.php` and try running through the browser

Comment: did exactly as you said & the php showed on the page with a recurring error on the console,
"73VM123:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (call_manager.php:157)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (call_manager.php:81)". I am using MAMP for my local server & Sublime for my text editior if that matters.

Comment: can you create a pastebin post of the code and share the link and possibly screenshot of the errors?

Comment: Here is the pastebin code: https://pastebin.com/myhFQ4w8. Stackoverflow won't let me share a screenshot since I am a new member. That's why I just copied the error & pasted it in last comment. When I see the call manager in the browser, I see the form & below it is all the php code. It's displaying it instead of executing it.

Comment: the php is missing the initial `<` so it is beginning `?php` rather than `<?php`

Comment: Wow! Now it's working! Stupid mistake on my part. On the "waiting since" part, I want it to be counting how long the person is waiting in minutes & seconds., like "Waiting: 3 mins 5 secs", then "Waiting: 3 mins 6 secs." It should keep counting the minutes & seconds until the delete caller button is hit.

Comment: The version I have now is very different to the above ( been having a bit of fun with this ) but does have the wait time updating as you are after. There are a couple of pastes ~ call_manager.php ( https://pastebin.com/h5dsS5eb ) and thumbnail.php ( https://pastebin.com/cfVjhS1g ) ~ probably way more than you need so you may just need to cherry pick the little pieces of javascript etc that control the time count thingy

Comment: you have gone above & beyond, thank you so much!! It is awesome!!! I realize now I was never going to be able to do this on my own. You are a rock star!!

Comment: Glad that you have it all up and running. Thanks for letting me know ~ I'm still playing around with the idea a little ~ do away with sessions and just use XML but .... good luck and have a nice Christmas